# meteorhacks:aggregate error

Tags: meteor, aggregate, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to publish some data using meteorhacks:aggregate:

```
Meteor.publish('alleNascholingen',function() {
var self = this;

var nascholingenOverzicht = nascholingenCollectie.aggregate([
   //{$match: {creatorId: this.userId}},
   //{$project: {naam: 1, familienaam:1, nascholingen:1}},
   { $unwind : "$nascholingen" },
   { $sort: {
       "nascholingen.inschrijfMoment": -1
   }}
   ]);

_.each(nascholingenOverzicht, function(parent){
    _.each(parent, function(child){
        self.added('selectie', child._id, child);
    });
});


 self.ready()
});
```

I have two collections, one to store the aggregated data:

```
nascholingenCollectie = new Mongo.Collection('nascholingen');
nascholingenSelectie = new Mongo.Collection('selectie');
```

On my template I subscribe to the data:

```
Template.nascholingBeheer.onCreated(function() {
let self = Template.instance();

    self.subscribe('alleNascholingen', function () {
        setTimeout(function () {

        }, 300)
    })

})
});
```

I'm getting the following error in my chrome console:

```
collection.js:173 Uncaught Error: Expected to find a document to change
at Object.update (http://localhost:3000/packages/mongo.js?hash=c4281c0ff989ebee020f59f5a7b0735053cea5f7:246:29)
at Object.store.(anonymous function) [as update] (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=bc32a166cd269e06a394f9418e0024d805bab379:3613:48)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=bc32a166cd269e06a394f9418e0024d805bab379:4441:19
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?hash=cde485f60699ff9aced3305f70189e39c665183c:149:11)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=bc32a166cd269e06a394f9418e0024d805bab379:4440:13
at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?hash=cde485f60699ff9aced3305f70189e39c665183c:157:22)
at Connection._performWrites (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=bc32a166cd269e06a394f9418e0024d805bab379:4437:9)
at Connection._flushBufferedWrites (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=bc32a166cd269e06a394f9418e0024d805bab379:4423:10)
at Connection._livedata_data (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=bc32a166cd269e06a394f9418e0024d805bab379:4391:12)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use aggregation in Meteor publication, only in Meteor method. To work around that you could consider using this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/meteor-publish-join) (disclaimer: I am the author).

Comment: Well, the strange thing is that it used to work like this...But somehow I copied my files to a new folder and suddenly this error emerged. I used [this](http://joshowens.me/using-mongodb-aggregations-to-power-a-meteor-js-publication/) guide to do this.

Answer (score 1):

My bad...I found my error:

```
_.each(nascholingenOverzicht, function(parent){
_.each(parent, function(child){
    self.added('selectie', child._id, child);
});
});
```

should be:

```
_.each(nascholingenOverzicht, function(parent){

    self.added('selectie', parent._id, parent);

});
```